# Why does child div render half outside of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have run into this issue a couple times and have messed around with the code multiple times in order to combat it but nothing seems to work. I have my parent div which in this case is 'top_of_page' and my child div 'social_media_wrapper' which contains a list of social media icons. However these social media icons are rendering half outside of 'social_media_wrapper'. Meaning I can only see the top half of each icon. Thoughts?

```
<div id='top_of_page'>
<div id='social_media_wrapper'>
<ul id='social_media'>
<li><img src='images/facebook_icon.png' class='social_media_icon'></li>
<li><img src='images/twitter_icon.png' class='social_media_icon'></li>
<li><img src='images/instagram_logo.png' class='social_media_icon'></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

ul#social_media {
list-style-type: none;
}

ul#social_media li {
float: right;
}

.social_media_icon{
height:24px;
margin-right:5px;   
}


#social_media_wrapper{
position:relative;
height:24px;
max-width:200px;
background-color:white;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:3px;
float:right;
}

#top_of_page{
width:100%;
height:30px;
background-color:#1f1f1f;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Added display:inline to the ul and it fixed it. Thanks anyways guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes about because the `<ul>` element is **[block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** by default, and the list items attempt to offset by default as well.

To correct this, all you need to do is apply **[`display: inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** to the `ul`:

```css
ul#social_media {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#social_media li {
  float: right;
}

.social_media_icon {
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#social_media_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: right;
}

#top_of_page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='top_of_page'>
  <div id='social_media_wrapper'>
    <ul id='social_media'>
      <li><img src='http://placehold.it/100' class='social_media_icon'></li>
      <li><img src='http://placehold.it/100' class='social_media_icon'></li>
      <li><img src='http://placehold.it/100' class='social_media_icon'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```